# storing user preferences

Tags: asp.net

In my pages, the first thing I do when a page is being displayed is query a table called user preferences. I'm doing this for every page and I was wondering what are the options available to avoid repeating this query as the user jumps from page to page on my application.

Thanks.

Comment: The database would normally cache the table in such a situation so I'm not sure you're going to achieve huge performance increase. We do something similar on ExposureRoom (http://exposureroom.com) and we arrived at using the database after doing a lot of performance testing compared to other solutions such as caching in memory using things like memcached and recently Velocity. If you're having performance issues you may want to look at the design of your tables and queries and make sure you've got the correct indexes in place for the queries you're using. Cookies- if "settings" are few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either store the user preference in a Cookie or Session.

Some good reads for you:

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/57/session/

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495(v=vs.71).aspx

If both cases, check if the value is not null. If it is not null, use the Cookie or Session value. If it is null, populate your Session / Cookie value with the result of your database call.

This way you will only make this DB call once.